# Rigidbody2D goes over destination when moving with Vector2.Lerp

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, rigidbody

I'm rounding the position of an object (the blue cube) when the player stops pushing it using

```
Rigidbody2D.MovePosition(transform.position,RoundedPosition,lerpValue);
```

The object slides toward the desired position, and when it reaches it, it stops and then it moves about 0.05 units over the position it stopped.

Here's the script

```
bool IsPushing = false;
bool RoundingPosition = false;
Vector3 RoundedPos;
public float lerp;
Rigidbody2D PlayerRb;
Rigidbody2D rb;
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    PlayerRb = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

Vector3 GetRoundedPos()
{
    return new Vector3(Mathf.Floor(transform.position.x) + 0.5f, Mathf.Floor(transform.position.y) + 0.5f, 0);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        IsPushing = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        IsPushing = false;
        RoundingPosition = true;
        RoundedPos = GetRoundedPos();
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (IsPushing)
    {
        if (new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) == Vector2.zero)
        {
            RoundingPosition = true;
            RoundedPos = GetRoundedPos();
        }
        else
            RoundingPosition = false;
    }

    if (RoundingPosition)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, RoundedPos, lerp));
        if (Vector3.Distance(RoundedPos,transform.position) <= 0.0001f)
        {
            
            RoundingPosition = false;
            IsPushing = false;
            rb.MovePosition(RoundedPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Demonstration video:
[Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkTUHmlk414&ab_channel=Xenox369)

Comment: I have not used Unity in a very long time, so I can't be specific in what functions/methods you use to move Rigidbody (it's stuff like ApplyForce(x,y,z) and so on). But by doing MovePosition you are most likely overriding the physics engine and just directly changing it's transform->position. You can use things like ApplyForce, or set the Velocity of the Rigidbody instead of just settings its position.

Comment: How would I implement Adding force to it to make it stop at the wanted position smoothly ?

Comment: To be honest, on a grid based game which this looks to be, you are better off handing collision yourself. Simply check if some solid object occupies the space at say "Rounded Position 9,10" and if it does, then you do not allow that particular movement. If you wish to continue dabbling with the Rigidbody stuff, I would say you can set the velocity using your input values (you will also need to set a Max Velocity and if it goes over that you can use Mathf Clamp to lock it to that max. By doing this when it hits the block it should stop. However, again the rb stuff not perfect for this...

Comment: ...it may over-shoot the border of the colliders. To try doing without Rigidbody, Try to do a "pre move" in your code, and check for collision after doing the pre-move. If the is no collision, you then do the physical move. If there is , just deny the move and consume the input value without actually moving your character.

Comment: I would say ignore what I said about ApplyForce and investigate SetVelocity if you wish to persist using the rigidbodies

Comment: The problem is not with the collisions between the player or the cube movement when pushing it, the problem is when the player stops pushing and the cube moves itself to the rounded position of the grid.

Comment: Is part of your cube code forcing it to move to the grid aligned positions (rounded position)? Sorry, I don't know if I understood actually. Is the cube going to the position, or not. And what was the intended behaviour?

Comment: I added a link to a video in my question

Comment: Am I being blind, did you post the code for GetRoundedPos() anywhere here? Seems like as soon as it stops moving (is pushing=false), it moves to whatever it thinks "RoundedPosition" is. So it is almost certainly wrong that function (GetRoundedPos())

Comment: Added the whole script. I checked the value of roundedPos by making it a public variable and it stays the same

Comment: Are the grid and character graphics/sprites perfectly aligned? Almost looks like it snaps to the edge of the dark background squares

Comment: The Mathf Floor returns an int, but then you add 0.5f to it. Perhaps do the calculation seperate and add the 0.5f after when doing the position change. (well I am wrong as often is the case, Floor returns a float type. But it is rounded down to nearest int. sorry for confusion). Still this might be the problem.

Comment: Mathf.Floor returns a float, Mathf.FloorToInt returns a int. GetRoundedPosition does return the correct position, so it is not the problem

Comment: Another shot in the dark I'm afraid, but could it be the object is still carrying some velocity? Perhaps try SetVelocity(0,0) at the same time as MovePosition (in the RoundedPos==true) if block. I do doubt this though, because it seems you are not using the rigidbody physics to actually move it, so the Velocity values probably remain at zero the whole time.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. The velocity stayed the same after the player stopped pushing it.

Comment: Excellent, got there in the end :D Ah yes I see in the Unity docs MovePosition is actually a more complex function that simple "Move" and uses Lerping to move towards that position. Not sure why it didn't stop at the correct place but at least forcing Vel to zero gets the game playing how you wanted it to. I'll make it into a full answer for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Rigidbody may have some velocity remaining from the MovePosition calls. Try to add line "rb.velocity=Vector2.Zero;":

````
if (Vector3.Distance(RoundedPos,transform.position) <= 0.0001f)
        {
            
            RoundingPosition = false;
            IsPushing = false;
            rb.MovePosition(RoundedPos);
            rb.velocity=Vector2.zero;
        }
```
````